# Altium 15 - Cannot see traces in 3D view

Tags: pcb, altium, trace

I am new to PCB designing and I've finished creating the my first prototype board. I want to send it to get printed but I'm worried that I haven't done my traces correctly because they do not show up in the 3D viewer. Looking at other renderings from Altium I can see the traces on the top layer. Have I done this incorrectly or is there a setting I need to turn on to see them?

**2D View:**
[image]

**3D View:**
[image]

Comment: If the first picture is a screen shot of your finished board, it looks to me like the grey ones aren't routed. (Not an Altium expert).

Comment: Yeah I didn't route those because I'm going to just use thick wire to connect them. Have to support 15ish amps going through and I believe the trace width would have to be enormous (I'm not EE though, I'm SE that's dabbling in EE)

Comment: I think the traces don't show in 3D view. That saves a lot of complexity in the rendering. You should be using 3D view more to make sure your connectors don't clash and your tall parts aren't too tall; not to check on where traces are located.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong. If you look closely at your picture, you will see the traces do render. They're just very faint where they're covered by soldermask. Look closely at one of the pads with a trace entering it and you'll see it.

Comment: Maybe check your Gerbers to be sure.

Comment: You're running 15A in/out of something which looks to be in a TO92 size package !? Good luck with that ......

Comment: My 12v connector is rated for 24amps and each of the mosfets that are going to be going in those slots are only going to take up to 4amps so hopefully I don't burn my house down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several 3D display modes:

[image: Display Modes]

And there's other controls too, in the View Configuration screen (press L):

[image: View Config]

In particular, the Solder Mask can either be turned off, or its opacity turned down to reveal the copper tracks under it.

Answer (score 1):

If you change to Single-Layer-Mode (Shift S) you can see them as well.

[image]